# Google Apps Script: how to search certain column for words from list and return text to another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a product descriptions in one column (A), and want to create tags in another column (B) based on what's in the descriptions.

I have a list of previous tags in C1. I want to compare what's in column A with what's in C1 and then return only those words, that have been matched.

So in the image below, the comparison has happened and a match was found and added to column B.

[image]

I have tried a few things but failed miserably. I initially thought it would work with a script that copies the description to column B, adds commas between all words and then does a search and replace for specific word combinations. But I realized that I would have to define 1000s of conditions (like not including 'is', etc.)

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it.

```
function findingWords()
{
  var criteriaRowIndex = 1, criteriaColIndex = 2;//indexes in rngA are just row and column numbers -1
  var descriptionColIndex = 0;
  var tagsFoundColIndex = 1
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  var criteriaA = String(rngA[criteriaRowIndex][criteriaColIndex]).split(',');
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    var strA = String(rngA[i][descriptionColIndex]).split(' ');
    var tagA = [];
    for(var j=0;j<criteriaA.length;j++)
    {
      if(strA.indexOf(criteriaA[j]) != -1)
      {
        tagA.push(criteriaA[j]);
      }
    }
    rngA[i][tagsFoundColIndex]=tagA.join();
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
}
```

[image]

I added some intermediate variables to help identify the rows and columns for you. But basically rows, columns start at one and indexes in an array created with getValues() start at zero.  So in general indexes are row and column numbers minus one.

Comment: thanks - this works great! I'm struggling to re-define the columns that are used though. In my real life case, the description, tags and search criteria aren't A-C but spread throughout the sheet. I thought it would be as easy as changing the numbers in the [], but that breaks the script and I can't work out why.

Comment: Okay I'll use some intermediate variables to make that clearer for you.

Comment: There you go.  I hope that helps you helps you to re-define the columns.

Comment: Yes, now I can re-define the columns - thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using sheet formulas.

I just cobbled this together so there is likely a more optimal way to do this but this should work.

Create a two-column sheet with a Product Description and a Found Tags column (Sheet1). Additionally create a one-column sheet with a list of all the tags you want to test for, with one and only one tag per row(Sheet2).

Here a link to a sample sheet with the layout you'll need:

[SAMPLE SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTrB_onabzS3yX4jjFYQeFwnHmFa29-ux9nMW0bn-XE/pubhtml#)

Then in Sheet 1, put the following formula into as many cells in column B as needed (starting from B2):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ",IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),Sheet2!A2:A))))), "\s+", ",")
```

Comment: This is a really cool solution as well! I was looking for a script but this excellent as well, many thanks